# Why don't national leaders wear their national costume more often?

Tags: political-leaders, symbols

Example: the national costume of Malaysia for men is the [Baju Melayu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baju_Melayu). The current Malaysian Prime Minister is Muhyiddin Yassin. Googling for images of him, we find lots of photos of him in a suit and tie, but comparatively few of him in a Baju Melayu. Why? It seems especially appropriate for him to do so at venues where he is representing the country, e.g. at international meetings, but no - usually every male leader at these meetings wears suits and ties. Female leaders wear more varied clothing, but still nobody wears their country's traditional costume.

A first guess is that traditional costumes are usually impractical to wear, but that doesn't seem like the case - e.g. the [Tangzhuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangzhuang), [Sarafan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarafan) and [Kilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilt) all look very wearable.

Comment: Some do (Narendra Modi and Pakistani leaders come to mind). Some also wear something that might not be a proper national costume but is chosen as a deliberate rejection of formal Western/European business attire (Muammar Gaddafi, Mobutu Sese Seko).

Comment: There is a photo from 2017 which went viral a while ago where a representative from Papua New Guinea [appeared at the UN wearing traditional tribal wear](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/c2ultq/united_nations_representative_from_papua_new/). But that was a one-time thing he did to make a point.

Comment: I think the correct word in this context is "regalia", rather than "costume", as the latter is more of a theatrical word, while "regalia" relates more to what a citizen would wear to a formal social function. But that's just a nitpick of language.

Comment: The Kilt is worn without any kind of undergarment, which might not be the best choice for e.g. negotiations where you sit across from each other, press conferences where you stand on a stage, coming down or walking up the stairs of your airplane, the classic photo op in chairs side-by-side facing the audience, and probably many other typical situations a politicians might find themselves in.

Comment: I'd assume that traditional costumes are OK to wear (traditional every-day clothing comparatively practical, festive clothing maybe somewhat less so - but not utterly impractical) *in their traditional environment*.  But how is the UN to set their AC for fair discussions if delegates come in their traditinal clothing ranging from tropical to arctic and high mountain climates?

Comment: Alex Salmond used to wear a kilt all the time. It was always good for a picture in the papers; https://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/news/uk-world-news/salmond-lets-hang-out-latest-11769319

Comment: @computercarguy no, if you don't like "costume" then then better word is "dress". The "regalia" is the complete formal dress of a monarch, and totally impractical for conducting any actual work in.

Comment: @OrangeDog, not really. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regalia Regalia has changed definitions over the years, and I'm talking about the modern version. Also, "dress" can be too easily mistaken for what typically only women wear, such as a sun dress or or wedding dress. The US military does use "dress" when referring to their dress uniform as their formal attire, but this isn't a normal AmE usage, unless you say that someone is going to "dress up" for an occasion.

Comment: @computercarguy I have never encountered "national dress" being mistaken as an item of women's clothing, in AmE nor BrE. Your link also doesn't back up your argument at all, and indeed it specifically mentions regalia for a president often consisting of a sash. Nothing to do with national dress.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I didn't say the link had anything to do with "dress", just "regalia". It does, however, back up my assertion about the current definition meaning "formal wear" that isn't just royal attire. And reading it again, it does use the word "dress", so we're both correct. "but now the word usually refers to any type of elaborate formal dress and dress accessories."

Comment: @computercarguy, "Regalia" might have extended its meaning from the attire of a king to other functionaries, but it definitely still implies clothing and accessories that indicate status and authority, especially garb that distinguishes them from the masses. National costume, by contrast, tends to be a leveller: it conveys very little in the way of social status.

Comment: Please clarify what *"national costume"* refers to.  It would help to include several examples.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Why should they? What advantage do they gain from wearing some traditional costume? Wearing traditional costumes has some implications:

- What is an appropriate "traditional costume" for a country? Is the bavarian leather pants representative for Germany? Surely not. Wearing the traditional costume of your region may be considered inappropriate or even offensive in other regions of the same country. A suit is neutral
- It is often only a cliche. If people do not wear these kind of clothing in everyday life, why wear it on international meetings?
- Other countries do not do it, especially not the rich western countries. Why single yourself out with clothing? It immediately creates a visual difference between "the rich westerners" and "the others"

Comment: A suit is not neutral at all, this answer is very superficial and completely misses the historical background and political implications of that choice.

Comment: Your comment misses the point. I never claimed a suite is neutral world-wide (although this is more or less how it evolved historically). But within a country it is not associated with any specific region, ethnicity, etc while "traditional clothing" is typically only linked to parts of the country

Comment: Your answer clearly assumes it is neutral in every way, which it is not, and consequently completely misses the issues raised by the question or, indeed, my comment. I wasn't even specifically referring to the first bullet point, this is just as obvious in the third one! At the very least, you would need to touch upon the history of why it became common in government circles everywhere (and that would clearly show that it isn't neutral *at all*). Incidentally, it's not the case that other costumes are always strongly associated with a specific region so that doesn't explain much.

Comment: @Relaxed - While you may be correct, the fact is that what matters for practical purposes is whether *world leaders* perceive it as neutral, which all the evidence suggests they *do*.  Even a number of staunchly anti-Western, anti-imperialist leaders (or at least, who would describe themselves as such) can regularly be spotted wearing tailored suits.

Comment: I think in conjunction with their comment, they really hit on one major reason for the popularity of European styles, languages, etc. across the world. For instance, the fact that Spanish is the official language of Equatorial Guinea is often justified by appealing to the difficulty of choosing between Bubi, Fang, Ndowe, et cetera. Whatever group had their language selected (probably Fang) would be seen as favored, and the others as disfavored. So by some people. Spanish is seen as "neutral" in a sense (others, of course, disagree).

Comment: @Obie2.0 Who counts as “world leaders”? Why is it all that matter? An answer treating that as obvious, devoid of any historical context is still very superficial and almost completely useless. Leading with “Why should they?” when many actually do and some explicitly do it for very specific political reasons just adds insult to injury and is deeply ignorant.

Comment: In fact, many leaders, especially anti-imperialist leaders, who chose to wear western business attire (or military uniforms) all the time or at specific occasions also do it very deliberately (just as your language example, which is indeed very common). It's not neutral at all!

Comment: @Relaxed - Like it or not (obviously *not*), many people see it as neutral, because it does not have any ties to their country. You seem to think that it is impossible to deliberately choose an option that one sees as neutral, which might be part of the discrepancy here.... But in reality, we are dealing with a situation where something is chosen deliberately, but because it is perceived as *neutral* (i.e. not having a bias toward one side or the other).

Comment: And, further, often suits are *not* chosen even to be neutral, but just because it's what *all the other politicians* wear in the country.

Comment: As for why world leaders are all that matter, I refer you to the title of the question....

Comment: Wearing the traditional costume of your region may also be considered inappropriate or offensive by people who wear such costumes, if they feel you're trying to appropriate the costume or that it's primarily a political stunt.

Comment: The first point should be easily sidestepped? Just rotate between the traditional outfits for each region.

Comment: @Allure: Here in Germany, distinct traditional costumes are regional on a very small scale. I just looked up the web site of the "traditional costume clubs' state association" for my Land (state/province), Hessen. It lists 33 different ones. That is 1 of 16 German Länder. And I don't think this variety is exceptional on a global scale.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: In the context of the question, it's important to note that costumes for men show far less regional variation than those for women. For formal occasions, the _Gehrock_ (frock coat) and later the _Sakko_ (suit jacket) have been the primary choice for men since the mid-19th century at least in most parts of what was to become Germany. Probably this goes hand in hand with the rise of Prussian hegemony, which strengthens the point that the suit isn't exactly neutral – it's probably no accident that it's regions like Bavaria and Hamburg that have distinctive male costumes.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I think you completely misunderstood my point, whether *I* like it is completely irrelevant, I don't care much actually. Being able to make a distinction between different points of view is essential to begin to analyze this (or anything in the social sciences). I would have no problem with an answer stating that it is chosen for its perceived neutrality (if it could provide some evidence for that of course). That's completely different from considering it as objectively neutral to the point that you cannot seem to comprehend why people could possibly make another choice.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Indeed, as you correctly point out, a Western suit is most often *not* chosen as a neutral choice but, e.g. as a deliberate rejection of traditional identities, a performance of modernity or international respectability, a way to signal your belonging to a specific social or political class, etc. All that is completely missing and cannot even be discussed if you assume, as this answer does, that wearing a suit is, always and everywhere, neutral and unproblematic. It isn't, it's *meaningful* and that's really the gist of my objection.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Finally, regarding *As for why world leaders are all that matter, I refer you to the title of the question....* My question was in relation to “While you may be correct, the fact is that what matters for practical purposes is whether world leaders perceive it as neutral” It doesn't follow at all from the title of the question! Obviously, world leaders also dress, act and talk for their domestic audience, even on the international stage. I am pretty sure that most of them are acutely aware of that and a little more sophisticated than this answer in their choice of garment.

Comment: I do find it surprising that the business suit is so popular around the world, rather than being seen as a symbol of 19th century British colonial imperialism. As a Brit, I also find it rather incomprehensible that if we wear clothing characteristic of other nations, we're accused of cultural appropriation, whereas everyone in the world (well, every male) wears the dress of a traditional British gentleman with impunity.

Comment: @MichaelKay Certainly not every man (most people do not wear suits at all) and certainly not as a copy of any British suit in particular. Even though the modern cuts may have originated there, suits were worn by the urban population of the whole Europe already in the 18th century. Various cuts and styles changed as the fashion changed and the latest ones may originate in the Edwardian summer suits or the formal ones from whatever Victorian, but that is just one particular style. The urban population of Europe of the 18th century did not wear any national dress.

Answer (score 39):

### National costumes represent old traditions

In most countries the "national costume" is essentially historical reenactment which represents the way these people dressed in, for example, 18th century. It is not a reflection of how the people dressed before or after that, in general, you will have very, very different "traditional dress" in different ages and centuries. And, more importantly, in many cases (though not all) it's not a reflection of how people of that nation dress now and it would be unusual for *any* person to wear it  outside of specific events that are about old traditions.

Furthermore, many "national costumes" (of which I'm aware of, mostly around Europe - perhaps e.g. Asia is very different) reflect a traditional  *peasant* attire - often focusing on the wealthier segment of farmers, but not something that a politician or nobleman would have *ever* worn in history.

Comment: Yes. You don't see Americans dressing like pilgrims or Englishmen dressing in wigs (alright maybe bad example...the latter happens in certain venues).

Comment: But the suit & tie represents an old Western tradition, and is not normal dress for the great majority of American men.  In a lot of places, "suit" is a term of contempt, used for people in management (or lawyers &c) that are far removed from any understanding of practical problems.

Comment: A number of American politicians have worn cowboy boots and big hats, even a few Presidents. Does that count? It is, as this answer suggests, evocative of an old tradition.

Comment: @Robyn: If you happen to live in the rural West, "cowboy boots" (at least the non-fancy versions) and hats are practical everyday working/recreating attire.  Far more so than a suit :-)

Comment: This is correct. For example, the modern-day kilt that Scots sometimes wear to weddings was ordinary street attire for only a short period in the 1700's. It is based on an even older traditional garment going back to the Middle Ages, but no one but re-enactors (e.g. SCA) actually wear the old version (which was more like a large blanket that was draped around the body).

Answer (score 25):

[image: Saudi Arabians wearing traditional dress]
[image: Xi Jingping wearing traditional suit]
[image: Iranian ayatollah wearing traditional dress]
[image: Gaddafi wearing traditional dress]
[image: African union members some of whom are wearing traditional dress]
[image: King of Bhutan wearing traditional dress]
[image: Indian politicians in traditional dress]
[image: Pope in pope outfit, no shit]
[image: State opening of parliament]

Most leaders want to strike a balance - on one hand, establishing their distinct national sovereignty and the fine cultural traditions they come from, and how the legitimacy of their rule stretches back many generations; on the other, that they're modern, up-to-date and of course if you visit or trade with us you won't feel alienated or suffer unexpected troubles due to our unfamiliar culture.

Needless to say, a lot of this depends on how people dress in your home country right now - on cultural inertia. The Pope wearing the traditional outfit is completely normal, but if the Irish Taoiseach attended meetings in a St Patrick's Day outfit, that would seem less traditional and more bizarre.

Comment: Note that many of the rulers wearing traditional dress in this picture are autocratic rulers.

Comment: Nobody in the last two pictures is wearing anything that would be considered "National costume". It's the formal dress for their office, not for their nationality.

Comment: @DJClayworth Pope Francis actually does *not* wear the formal dress for his office. He rejected the traditional papal mozzetta from day one of his papacy and instead opted for a more simple outfit.

Comment: Good info, but my point is still that it's the dress he has chosen to represent his office, not the costume of his nationality - either Argentinian or Vatican.

Comment: And don't forget the "strongmen" who usually wear a military uniform.

Comment: @DJClayworth You're right about the Pope not wearing national dress or being a national leader - I included that for two reasons: (1) because he's not wearing a suit despite being sort of equivalent to a national leader; and (2) to represent the fact some important westerners do wear funny-looking non-suit outfits to state events - it's not just autocrats and Africans who don't wear suits.

Comment: @mjt Actually the Pope is a national leader. He is the head of state of the Vatican. But for the rest, yes.

Comment: @mjt I fail to see the significant difference between an autocrat and an absolute monarch, like the pope.

Comment: @DJClayworth If the Vatican has a national dress, then he basically is wearing it. A large chunk of its citizens regularly wear something very similar, just not in white.

Comment: Many do, but many outside the Vatican wear it too. and any citizen of the Vatican not entitled to wear it would be very much frowned on. In short, it's the dress of an office, not a nation.

Comment: Vatican is a rather special case. Because a pope (as in the head of the state) has to be a catholic bishop as well. That forces some dressing rules on him due to religious laws.

Comment: Also whether there is such thing as "vatican nation" is arguable as well. There is such state but nation? Are citizens of the Vatican City any different from citizens of Rome? Are members of the catholic church citizens of the Vatican? If if they are not formally, they do serve and obey laws of the Holy See. But there are huge cultural differences even between priests in different parts of the world. As I said: a special case.

Answer (score 14):

**International diplomacy tends to focus on commonalities, not differences.**

When world leaders meet at international events, the goal is typically to come to some agreement. Highlighting the differences between two nations does nothing to further that end, and only reinforces the notion that the nations are unlike one another. Strong diplomatic ties are often formed between nations that are like one another historically or ideologically or politically, while starkly different nations may not get along as well.

Entering a meeting where you hope to find common ground with another person while wearing something that screams "we are not the same" does not engender a spirit of working together. Traditional costumes may have their place at events that seek to highlight diversity or world cultures, but they won't help world leaders come to terms on economic, human rights, or climate issues, and may actually act as a detriment.

Answer (score 9):

The question you should ask yourself is what would a Western European or North American leader be wearing at a time when national dress would be appropriate. The answer is probably military uniform (in the small number of cases that would be appropriate), or black tie ( aka the Tuxedo), or more likely white tie (i.e. a white bow tie and a tail coat) for men, or a similarly formal evening gown for a woman.

You'll note that there are similarly few photos of such leaders dressed like that as well. The majority of photos of heads of government are when they are at business, in business attire. That doesn't necessarily mean a lounge suit, but doesn't mean the kind of national dress you seem to be thinking of, which are mostly highly formalized versions of the traditional clothes of rural workers.

Comment: North American leaders certainly have [other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Salazar#/media/File:20081217_PRESSER-5055.jpg).

Comment: But then we have to ask why military uniforms (I mean dress uniforms, not combat fatigues) of other cultures are such blatant copies of western European ones?

Comment: @jamesqf That one is the end result of imperialism, coupled with parallel developments in technology for the areas which either remained independent or gained independence earlier than others.

Comment: Really it would depend on the time of day.  The European/American tradition both "black tie" and "white tie" are "evening dress" and not to be worn during the day.  A "morning coat" is the daytime counterpart to white tie - if you look back to say WW1 era diplomacy, you'll see them worn for formal daytime meetings.  A business suit is the daytime counterpart to black tie, and today you see that and black tie, with white tie only worn at the most extremely formal evening occasions by someone desiring to protect an image of tradition rather than modernity, and the morning coat basically extinct.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat popular in diplomacy. Ex:

https://www.novinite.com/articles/195780/The+Ambassador+of+Bulgaria+to+India+Took+Office+in+a+Folk+Costume

Then again, most national costumes are pretty much impractical for office-bound work of any kind. They simply evolved for other purposes.

In a national context, they can express (using small regional differences) a preference between national fractions (there are always some). A national leader is not expected to do that.

In international context, it is like not speaking [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) - you can still do your job, but you are suboptimal at best.

Answer (score 0):

Some national costumes is inappropriate to wear daily (for example i have access to one such, a swedish one but it was only used at marriage by the man.)

Other ones is i would say entirely appropriate for example this one:
[Lekatts Karin i Söndagsdräkt ie Sunday church dress](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/Kvinna%2C_i_helfigur%2C_Lekatts_Karin_i_S%C3%B6ndagsdr%C3%A4kt._P._S%C3%B6dermark_1850_-_Nordiska_museet_-_NMA.0070034.jpg/103px-Kvinna%2C_i_helfigur%2C_Lekatts_Karin_i_S%C3%B6ndagsdr%C3%A4kt._P._S%C3%B6dermark_1850_-_Nordiska_museet_-_NMA.0070034.jpg)

[swedish wikipedia about Leksanddräkten, dress from Leksand in Dalecarlia](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leksandsdr%C3%A4kten)