# Why do anti-Western politicians wear Western suits?

Tags: russian-federation, china, protocol

Whenever I see press releases about China or Russia I am always puzzled that Putin and Xi (and everyone below them) wear suits in Western style despite their anti-Western sentiments. The dominance of the Western suit and tie might be normal (or strange) for politicians from countries that not aligned with the Western world, such as some African countries, but seems especially weird to me for leaders that show direct enmity towards the Western world and culture. I would expect Xi and Putin with their nationalist conduct to choose a more national attire instead of wearing the style of the "enemy".

As counter-example, the Indian prime minister Narendra Modi wears some kind of Indian suit (I guess), which also suits him very nicely (pun intended).

Is there a specific reason that anti-Western politicians are wearing Western suits? Is the cultural origin of the politician's attire ever discussed in these countries? If not, why?

Comment: The question sounds off topic to me. Also Putin was not anti Western at the begining.

Comment: Can you be sure about that? Or did he simply not act on his intentions? Anyway, this question asks about the more recent time.

Comment: "style of the "enemy""? How many Chinese for example war a suit and tie nowadays? This question might underestimate the global popularity of business attire. It's international nowadays. Xi Jinping just wears what anyone else in his country wears. It's not a Western suit & tie, it's just a suit and tie.

Comment: Some African and Middle Eastern leaders wear more traditional dress, but have you noticed what ordinary people in Russia wear? It's almost entirely Western clothing, and has been for a long time; look at the later tsars of Russia, who are typically depicted in western-style military uniform. China is more complex, with Mao having his own style, but again everyday Chinese clothes today are largely western (even more than e.g. Japan which preserves older styles in some contexts) - a question about the political significance of Chinese clothing might be interesting.

Comment: When Gandhi was invited to have tea with King George V at Buckingham Palace in 1931, a reporter asked: *“Mr Gandhi, do you think you are
properly dressed to meet the king?"* Gandhi who was wearing a sparse traditional indian dress replied: *"Do not worry about my clothes. The king has enough clothes on for both of us.”*  Indian political culture has historically tended to project its eastern-western blend of cultural heritage internationally through the clothes its political leaders wear. Others tend to lean toward playing it safe and stick to western attires when meeting western leaders.

Comment: see also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57179/why-dont-national-leaders-wear-their-national-costume-more-often/57181#57181

Comment: Voted not to reopen - duplicate Q to https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57179/45056

Comment: What was the situation in the old USSR like in this regard?

Comment: Sartorially, Russia's modern norms aren't different from those of the rest of Europe. Russians haven't dressed in "traditional costume" for day to day business since sometime in the 1700s or earlier 1800s.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The current question is more narrow and is specifically asking something very different (it is about the cognitive dissonance of *anti-western* rhetoric and *western*-style clothes), compared to the alleged dupe target (about *national* clothes of politicians *in general*, whether they are anti-western or not). Note that the current Q asks "Why do **anti-Western** politicians wear Western suits?" Meanwhile, the alleged dupe asks "Why don't **national** leaders wear their national costume more often?"

Comment: The opposite is true, where the Ukrainian leaders are big fans of Ukrainian folk dressing.

Comment: "western-style clothes" could somebody kind of define this? Lederhosen maybe? Because I believe suit and business attire are international by now?

Comment: Because this suit is not considered "Western" or "from a different culture" in Russia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Western business wear and military uniform is a signature of Russian state since [Peter the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_reform_of_Peter_the_Great).

The suits themselves are likely made in Italy, which was never a dominant economical or military power in modern history, neither was it exceedingly Russophobic.

It also seems weird to call Russian position "anti-West". Russia is opposed to the current political and military trends of the West, but not opposed to Western culture and history, and indeed an integral part of that culture and history.

Comment: Well, Stalin did try to be abit more distinctive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin_tunic But it's fair to say that the post-Soviet Russia wasn't trying to be on the same level of ideological difference from the West. And even the Stalinka was allegedly a (simplified) derivative of a French military  tunic, if Wikipedia is to be believed on that.

Comment: Stalin tunic evolved from Western-style military uniform, which kind of reinforces my point.

Answer (score 3):

From my personal observations, high-quality, brand-name Western clothes, such as Western suits and accessories, such as watches, were always viewed in the post-Soviet states (especially Russia) as a status symbol. Out of the plethora of national clothes and accessories, only the crosses (worn on the body) are popular among the ruling elites, the rest are not.

I am not sure why the Chinese ruling elite wears Western clothes, but I assume that for same reason (status).

---

Fun fact: even the religious leader of Russia, [Patriarch Kirill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarch_Kirill_of_Moscow), wore a very expensive Swiss Breguet watch worth over $30,000 together with his traditional Russian clothes, a fact that Russians have unsuccessfully tried to conceal.

[image: Kirill and his disappearing watch]

*The original (right) and the doctored picture of Patriarch Kirill at a meeting with then Russian Justice Minister Aleksandr Konovalov in July 2009. Note the watch's reflection still visible in the table top in the doctored photo.*

*Claire Bigg, "Patriarch's Swiss Watch Does Disappearing Act". Radio Free Europe/Radio Liberty, April 05, 2012: https://www.rferl.org/a/russian_patriarch_watch_disappearing_act/24539007.html*

Comment: I'm not sure what's particularly "Western" about Swiss golden watches. Switzerland didn't invade Iraq or mess with Lybia in my memory.

Comment: @alamar Switzerland is located in Western Europe. It is also a Western democracy. This makes the watch a "Western" product. Note that traditional Eastern attire of Patriarch Kirill, in contrast to the Western-made (not Russian-made) watch.

Comment: @alamar Switzerland is also part of the civilized world of Western democracies - witness its sanctions policy against the Russian war criminals: *"The international community applauded Switzerland when it finally decided to join EU sanctions against Russia at the end of February 2022."* ([How the war in Ukraine has changed Switzerland - SWI swissinfo.ch](https://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/business/how-the-war-in-ukraine-has-changed-switzerland/48309654)). Which makes a Swiss watch even more Western.

Comment: I'm not sure that Patriarch's ornate robes, the table or the vase in the background are made in Russia. Why would watch stick out specifically. Switzerland realistically has no choice but comply with what the USA and Germany tell it to do, so it may seen as a victim of circumstances. Russia is not opposed to democracy (it just haven't got one).

Answer (score 1):

**Russia**

A central theme of Putin's propaganda is Russia's role as the leading defender of Christianity and traditional European values. The suit was invented in the 19th century, it predates womens suffrage, gay rights and most of the other facets of liberal democracy that Putin is against. As such, it actually makes a lot of sense for Putin to wear a suit as a kind of "symbol of Western civilization before it's Fall".

**China**

While China has taken a more nationalistic stance in recent years, the whole raison d'etre of the communist party is the break with the ancient regime. Again, keep in mind that the invention of the suit predates the foundation of the Chinese Communist Party. Mao is so famous for wearing a particular style of suit that "Mao suit" is a thing now. Ditching suits and wearing eg Ming or Qing inspired regalia would be a huge break in continuity - and quite certainly very much unrelated to the fact that suits are originally European.

Comment: Well, China has stopped Revolution-themed naming of their space missions in favor of traditional Chinese imagery, I can imagine such change happen to Chinese leaders' image as well.

Comment: The "Hanfu movement" does seem to be a thing in China, but it does not seem to have affected the world of power politics.